# Creating a Simple Calculator Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a simple calculator function but I'm not getting the values to show up. I know I'm missing something but not sure exactly what it is. Right now, I'm only working on addition and will work on the others (multiplication, subtraction, and division).
My HTML code is this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <title> Simple Calculator </title>
                    <meta charset="utf-8">
                        <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
                        <script src="js/assignment03.js"></script>



            </head>

                <body>

                     <h1>Calculator</h1>
                        <label for="num1">Number1</label>
                        <br>
                        <input id="num1" name="num1" type="text" value="0"/>
                        <br>
                        <label for="num2">Number 2</label>
                        <br>
                        <input id="num2" name="num2" type="text" value="0"/>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                            <a id="action" href="#">Click Here to Calculate </a>


                                <div>The result of adding the numbers is: <span id="result-add"></span></div>


                </body>

        </html>
```

My Javascript code is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#action').click(function() {
    //DO NOT CHANGE CODE BELOW
        var num1 = parseInt($('#num1').val());
        var num2 = parseInt($('#num2').val());
        clear();
        addNumbers(num1, num2);
        var result = multiplyNumbers(num1, num2);
        $('#result-mult').text(result);
    //DO NOT CHANGE CODE ABOVE

    });

    /*
     Below this comment, create a function 
     named addNumbers, which accepts two parameters.
     The function should add the two parameters together
     and write the result to the element with the id
     result-add
    */
function addNumbers (num1, num2) {
    var retVal = num1 + num2;
    retVal = ("#result-add");
    return retVal;

};
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You want to set the `innerHTML` property of the element.  In jQuery you can do that with `text`.

```
$("#result-add").text(retVal);
```

You also don't need to `return` from your function if its only purpose is to create the side effect of setting the text in your element.

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing your js code as follow:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#action').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    //DO NOT CHANGE CODE BELOW
        var num1 = parseInt($('#num1').val());
        var num2 = parseInt($('#num2').val());
        let result = addNumbers(num1, num2);

        $('#result-add').text(result);
    //DO NOT CHANGE CODE ABOVE

    });

    /*
     Below this comment, create a function 
     named addNumbers, which accepts two parameters.
     The function should add the two parameters together
     and write the result to the element with the id
     result-add
    */
            function addNumbers (num1, num2) {
                var retVal = num1 + num2;
                return retVal;

            }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

currently **clear() and multiplyNumbers()** is not defined in you code so it's give an error and you can set result of addation from its function ** $("#result-add").html(retVal)**.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#action').click(function() {
    //DO NOT CHANGE CODE BELOW
        var num1 = parseInt($('#num1').val());
        var num2 = parseInt($('#num2').val());
        //clear();
        addNumbers(num1, num2);
        //var result = multiplyNumbers(num1, num2);
        //$('#result-mult').text(result);
    //DO NOT CHANGE CODE ABOVE

    });

    /*
     Below this comment, create a function 
     named addNumbers, which accepts two parameters.
     The function should add the two parameters together
     and write the result to the element with the id
     result-add
    */
 })
function addNumbers (num1, num2) {
    var retVal = num1 + num2;
    $("#result-add").html(retVal);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <title> Simple Calculator </title>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
                <script src="js/assignment03.js"></script>
           </head>
           <body>
             <h1>Calculator</h1>
             <label for="num1">Number1</label>
             <br>
             <input id="num1" name="num1" type="text" value="0"/>
             <br>
             <label for="num2">Number 2</label>
             <br>
             <input id="num2" name="num2" type="text" value="0"/>
             <br>
             <br>
             <a id="action" href="#">Click Here to Calculate </a>
             <div>The result of adding the numbers is: <span id="result-add"></span></div>
         </body>
    </html>
```